# search() method not working in Google Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

**Update**: Ok this was a simple fix. I selected the column of numbers I was inputting, and went to Format -> Number -> Plain Text, and all of a sudden my function worked! If I change it to Format -> Number -> Normal or anything else, it threw an error.

---

I have a method that adds zeros to a start of a string if it's less than 9. I'm getting an error that the function `search` is undefined, as in `issn.search` on line 4. What could possibly be causing this problem? Specifically, the error in Google Apps Script is `TypeError: Cannot call method "search" of undefined. (line 5)`

```
function fixissn(issn){
    //Logger.log("Old issn is " + issn);
    //if there's a dash in the ISSN, it need 9 characters instead of 8
    if (issn.search("-") > -1) {
        var mis = 9; 
    } else if (issn.search("-") == -1) {
        var mis = 8; 
    }

    //if the ISSN is less than 9 or 8 (mis), add zeros to the beginning
    while (issn.length < mis && issn.length > 0) {
        //zero added to beginning of ISSN
        issn = 0 + issn
    }
    //Logger.log("fixed to new issn " + issn);
    return issn;
}
```

Comment: You're sure you're getting a value passed in? You've got a commented out log message echoing the value so I assume that you've checked that. Also, are you passing in a string or a number? If `issn` is a number, trying to apply `search` to it will give an error, granted not the one in your message.

Comment: Nitpick: Why are you doing an else if? Just use an else there!

Comment: The problem is with calling the function fixissn and not the function.

Comment: Try just adding a condition on issn not null and force it to be a string then you shouldn't have any issue anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Just to echo what @epascarello stated, it looks like a value is not being passed in. It is hard to say but it might be due to you using this function on a range of cells, some of which are empty. To bypass that issue you might try something like:

```
function fixissn(issn){
    if (issn !== undefined) {
        //Logger.log("Old issn is " + issn);
        //if there's a dash in the ISSN, it need 9 characters instead of 8
        if (issn.search("-") > -1) {
            var mis = 9; 
        } else if (issn.search("-") == -1) {
            var mis = 8; 
        }

        //if the ISSN is less than 9 or 8 (mis), add zeros to the beginning
        while (issn.length < mis && issn.length > 0) {
            //zero added to beginning of ISSN
            issn = 0 + issn
        }
        //Logger.log("fixed to new issn " + issn);
    }
    return issn;
}
```